# VS Windows Form App, Controlling Hover State (not Blue)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

some of my button states in my Windows Form Application are defaulting to a blue Hover state.  I am pretty new to VS and I am mainly using the GUI to modify the design, but I don't see anywhere where I can control just the color of the hover state of the buttons.

Can anybody tell me where I control this, whether it be programatically or in the GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The windows operating system handles that.

To modify it, you would have to change the `FlatStyle` appearance to `Flat` and then modify the `FlatAppearance` attributes, which includes the `MouseOverBackColor` property.

Unfortunately, you lose the visual styles then.

Comment: Thanks, I found that if I just use a panel and put buttons in it then I don't get that blue hover state, only with the menustrip control.